# How does upsampling in Keras work?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I checked `Keras` documentation, but not get any specific explanation? Does it just simply repeat the value alone a certain axis?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the values are just repeated.

You have UpSampling1D/2D/3D, 1D will repeat each step size and 2D will repeat each column/row.